# Let $A$ is a square matrix of order $2016$ and $I$ is an identity matrix of the same order, where $A^TA=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove:

$A^T(A-I)=-(A-I)^T$

$\det A=1$ or $\det A=-1$

If $\det A=-1\Rightarrow \det(A-I)=0$

One example of a symmetric matrix is the identity matrix which satisfies these statements. How to generalize this proof?

Comment: Identifying that $A = I$ is a solution does not help at all here, especially if you want to "generalize" the "proof." A good start is computing $(A - I)^T$ in terms of objects on the left hand side of the equation. For the second part, look at how determinants behave under matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ and $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$ you get that $$A^T(A-I)=A^TA-A^T=I-A^T=I^T-A^T=-(A-I)^T$$ and $$1=\det(I)=\det(A^TA)=\det(A)\det(A^T)=\det(A)^2$$ which implies that $\det(A)=\pm 1.$ For the last one it comes from $$-\det(A-I)=\det(A-I)\underset{=-1}{\underbrace{\det(A^T)}}=\det(I-A)=(-1)^{2016}\det(A-I)=\det(A-I).$$